# Ejecutar Eventos de ASP.NET desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

mi problema es que tengo un formulario en ASP.NET en VB y tengo eventos declarados en ese programa, ahora necesito saber como ejecutar esos eventos desde javascript.
Evento de Visual

```
Protected Sub Cargar()
PanelSearch.Visible = False
End Sub
```

JavaSCript:

```
Function CargarDatos(){
document.getElementById("Button1").click();
};
```

El código de javascript me funciona pero solo cuando el "button1  es visible y como ven necesito ocultarlo, y al momento de ocultarlo ya no funciona.
Y tiene que ser de esa manera por que necesito que funcione con el javascript.
Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Creo que no me explique, lo que necesito es que desde javascript, ejecutar un evento de visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando quieras obtener la etiquetas de ASP en Javascript debes usar ClientIDs: `<%=IDVariable.ClientID%>`
Ejemplo:

ASP

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function CargarDatos(){
    document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
};
```

Otra opción para llamar a una funcion Javascript desde un Boton de ASP es usar el metodo onclientclick.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Runat="server" onClientClick="CargarDatos()"/>
```